# Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies... The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting an error on my ASPX file
after register control toolkit then also not access `<cc1:........>`.

Here is my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
     CodeFile="DropdownlistCSC.aspx.cs" Inherits="DropdownlistCSC" %> 
    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This is the error I am getting:

> Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have referenced the Ajax Control tool kit in your project. It should go to your bin folder

Comment: Wow! It's been 5 years since this answer and it's just been accepted! Thank you! I guess the "you're welcome" comment will come in 2025 :P

Answer (score 0):

This may happen because all of your ajax DLLs are not in the bin folder. AjaxControlToolkit.dll, AjaxMin.dll must be in the bin folder.

Comment: This is an almost identical answer to [Leo's from last year](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20591834/1454048).

Comment: @admdrew i don't think that. he just wrote about bin folder and AJAX. here I wrote name of the ajax dll